# Is there a way to debug lua application without 504 ERROR?

Tags: lua, virtual-machine, remote-debugging, zerobrane

My goal is to debug lua app running on nginx in vm remotely from my computer with ZeroBrane.
I succeed to activate the debugger, but Nginx 504 gateway timeout error causes the debugger to terminate (because the server doesn't respond in time in debug mode).
How can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do on the ZeroBrane side, as it will block the application under debugging (on the socket IO call), so it won't be able to proceed with the call handling. You may want to disable/extend gateway timeout using `proxy_{read|connect|send}_timeout` (or maybe `send_timeout`; I'm not sure which one is being triggered in this case).